# Spy on class member method call

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spy

I would like write something like this :

```
this.spyObject = Mockito.spy(myObject);
...
verify(this.spiedObject, atLastOnce()).getMember().doSomething(any(OneClass.class))
```

or

```
this.spyObject = Mockito.spy(myObject);
...
verify(this.spiedObject.getMember(), atLastOnce()).doSomething(any(OneClass.class))
```

in a Junit test,
knowing that the constructor of myObject is

```
public MyObject() {
    this.member = new Member()
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't works !

Finally, I would be able to verify `doSomething` was called on the `member`.
I'm pretty beginner with Mockito :)

Any help please ?

Comment: How about creating a new constructor `MyObject(Member member) { this.member = member; }` and passing a `spy(new Member())` into it... then you can do what you want

Comment: Why are you spying the object ? when you are going to check it with simple `verify()` method. Just use `mock()` instead of `spy()`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `Member` to be a spy too. In this case, you could do something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)    
public class SomeTestClass {
    private MyObject myObjectSpy;
    private Member memberSpy;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        memberSpy = spy(Member.class);
        myObjectSpy = spy(MyObject.class);
        doReturn(memberSpy).when(myObjectSpy).getMember();
        ...
        verify(memberSpy, atLeastOnce()).doSomething(any(OneClass.class));
    }
}
```

Be warned, including `doReturn(...)` with a spy is partial mocking if you intend to *only* mock `getMember()` and not its other functions. In that case, consider using a full mock and deciding what the return values of its other functions should be.